# JPA Hibernate manyToMany with non-unique key 

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, formula

I have two entities (tables): **Department** and **Person**. Both tables have a field *CODE* which is **not unique**.

How can I define manyToMany bidirectional relations between these tables?

1. Department has collection Persons which contains all entities with *Person.CODE eq Department.CODE*
2. Partner has collection Departments which contains all entities with *Department.CODE eq Partner.CODE*

I need the **relation definition** - no sql or hpql query.

it is no problem to do it with HPQL, but I need annotation.

Select persons for given departmentID:

```
select P.* from Person P, Deparment d  
where d.department_id = ? and 
p.code = d.code and 
? between d.validFrom and d.validTill and  
? between p.validFrom and p.validTill
```

It is possible with hibernate formula?

Answer (score 0):

You would definitely need a third table in the  DB to own the many-to-many relation to start with, call it `department_person`. Declare two foreign keys from this that refer to `Persons` and to `Departments` table.

Afterwards, you could either:

1) define a new JPA entity DepartmentPerson and define to many-to-one relations from each foreign key. You should consequently create two one-to-many relations which would point from `Persons` to
`DepartmentPerson`  and from `Department` to `DepartmentPerson` yielding the Collections you need.

2) define a many-to-many relation in one of the two initial entities stating that `department_person` is the owner of the relation.

Comment: There is no problem to create join table for manyToMany relations. Unfortunatelly it doesn't solve my problem. If I use MTM relation and insert updated department with existing code, I will have to assign all all persons to the new departmet.

Comment: I do not understand the problem exactly. Do you mean that you would have to update the data for a specific department keeping the same code or do you mean that you would have to update a specific relation? Being many-to-many you could have many persons assigned to one deparment and many departments that a person can be a member of.

Comment: I have department with code "XXX" and name "Dep1" which has 20 persons. I insert new department entity with code "XXX" and new name "Dep1 edited". (of course every entity has validFrom, validTill). If I use MTM relation I have to assign manually the 20 persons to the new department (fill relation table).

Comment: So if understand well, what you realy want is to avoid creating the relation holding table because the effort of creating the relation would be considerable. I dont know if this would help but the only other way of holding such a relation is using comma-separated values to hold multiple foreign keys from one table to the other. I know this is not an elegant solution but it is the only way to avoid the 3rd table

Comment: These two tables working well. It is not problem to write SQL or HPQL query which returns appropriate collection. You don't need CSV or third table because the search key is in both tables (record from both tables with same CODE belongs together). **But I am not able to write JPA annotation for it**

Comment: Then it is not a many-to-many but a one-to-many relation. The relationship may not be defined using foreign keys but you cannot assign a second department on a particular user, can you? Please correct me if i have missunderstood you case.

Comment: Department has many persons. Person belongs to many departments with same CODE. I think it is many-to-many